# getting xml cross site by using iframe

Tags: xml, iframe, xss

I am trying the above mentioned, like this:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'xml',                  
                    url: $('#proxy').attr('src', 'http://192.168.0.106:8111/getconfiguration?'),
                    success: function (xml) 
                 {//do stuff with xml
```

And in the body of my html page, i have a iframe like this:

```
<div><iframe id="proxy" src="" ></iframe></div>
```

It is hitting server and the server is returning the xml, but nothing happens. It seems to keep trying to process the xml. The error console in safari says:

```
Resource interpreted as other but transferred with MIME type text/html.
```

Any ideas, hints, things to try out??

---

Tried changing this:

```
var myxml = new String($('#proxy').attr('src', 'http://192.168.0.106:8111/getconfiguration?'));


$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'xml',                  
                    url: myxml,
                    success: function (xml)
```

but that didn´t wotk either - or am i doing this wrong?
I am new at JS

Comment: Change `myxml` to just be `http://192.168.0.106:8111/getconfiguration?`. But if you just want to change the `iframe`'s value, that one line will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the `url` property return a string.

From what I can tell, it will return a jQuery object here.

You probably want to set the URL just to `http://192.168.0.106:8111/getconfiguration?`, as the code you are using is setting the `src` attribute, but it won't be returning anything useful in that context